# GRASS make local relief error

Tags: grass-gis

While using/trying to make a local relief in GRASS with the plugin r.local.relief I stumble across a error.

```
ERROR: G_realloc: unable to allocate 15000000 bytes of memory at lib/vector/diglib/cindex.c:113
```

Does this mean that I don't have enough memory(got 16 GB) or that GRASS can't handle this size of data(the tiff is 477 MB) Or is it something totally different. I'm using Windows.

I discovered that the map lib/vector/diglib/cindex.c:113 doesnt exist.

my region is:

```
g.region -p                                                                     
projection: 99 (sterea)
zone:       0
datum:      rd18
ellipsoid:  bessel
north:      506250
south:      500000
west:       215000
east:       220000
nsres:      0.5
ewres:      0.5
rows:       12500
cols:       10000
cells:      125000000
```

Does someone know what the problem is?

This is the whole traceback:

```
Smoothing using r.neighbors...
Subtracting smoothed from original elevation...
Finding zero contours in elevation difference map...
Reading data...
Displacing data...
Writing vector contour (one level)...
WARNING: 890973 crossings found
Writing attributes...
Building topology for vector map <r_local_relief_7784_vector_contours_tmp@berend>...
Registering primitives...
Current region rows: 12500, cols: 10000
ERROR: G_realloc: unable to allocate 15000000 bytes of memory at lib/vector/diglib/cindex.c:113
Cleaning temporary maps...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\berend\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/script
s/r.local.relief.py", line 260, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\berend\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/script
s/r.local.relief.py", line 184, in main
    overwrite=gcore.overwrite())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS GIS
7.0.0\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 375, in
run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args,
kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS GIS
7.0.0\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 310, in
handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None
['r.contour',
'input=r_local_relief_7784_subtracted_smooth_elevation_tmp',
'levels=0',
'output=r_local_relief_7784_vector_contours_tmp'] ended with
error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the
(error) output.
(Fri May 22 11:46:33 2015) Command finished (10 min 1 sec)
```

Does someone knows what the problem is?

Comment: In general GRASS GIS 7 is able to manage huge datasets in the multi-GB size. Is your current region really rows: 12500, cols: 10000? Can you edit your posting and add the output of g.region -p just to better understand the problem?

Comment: i added the output

Answer (score 1):

I asked for you in the grass-dev list and obtained this answer - hope it helps:

https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2015-May/075188.html

> r.contour creates a DCELL array for the current region then reads the
>   raster data into it.
>
> 12500 rows by 10000 cols by 8 bytes per cell is 1 GB of memory, on top
>   of anything else the module uses. It's not inconceivable that the
>   system's configured resource limits don't allow a single process to
>   use that much.
>
> In such a situation, the first thing to do is to check the current
>   soft limits with "ulimit -a". If they are insufficient, check the hard
>   limits with "ulimit -aH". If the soft limits can be increased, do so;
>   otherwise, ask the system administrator to increase the hard limits
>   (these are normally set by the pam_limits module according to
>   /etc/security/limits.conf and/or /etc/security/limits.d/*).
>
> Soft limits are usually set below the hard limits to prevent a
>   misbehaving process from rendering the system unusable. On a
>   multi-user system, hard limits may be set to prevent a single user
>   from monopolising resource; there isn't much reason to set hard limits
>   on a single-user system.

Comment: i was already looking to increase the limit. But i don't really understand where i can find ulimit -a or put it in? any tips?

Comment: Right, on Windows things are different. According to http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Large_raster_data_processing#ERROR:_G_malloc:_unable_to_allocate_xxxx_bytes_of_memory_... you probably need to use a 64bit version of winGRASS 7.

Comment: well, i tried to find 64. but it is broken i guess. i will try it on linux one of these day. Just made a virtual box on my computer and i hope that that will work !